# Parameter has no value

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetime, select, parameters

```
string queryString = "SELECT SUM(skupaj_kalorij)as Skupaj_Kalorij  "
                    + "FROM (obroki_save LEFT JOIN users ON obroki_save.ID_uporabnika=users.ID)"
                    + "WHERE users.ID= " + a.ToString() + " AND obroki_save.datum =?";


using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString,database))                                    
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@datum", OleDbType.Char).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();    
}
```

Why doesn't the parameter datum get the date value? (the value of at least one complex parameter has not been determined )

Answer (score 4):

From the docs for [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL 
>   Statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. 
>   In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Try using the positional approach instead, basically.

Comment: Do you mean just like : Where datum=#"DateTime.Now()+"#";

Comment: @Simon: No, I mean using a "?" placeholder, as described in the quoted paragraph. Read the linked documentation for a fuller example.

Comment: Ok... But i can't make it work. How do i use that in my case (give the parameter the date value and compare it to the date in the database ?

Comment: @Simon: Just change the SQL statement to have "?" instead of @datum and I'd expect it to work. I don't know whether you need to remove the name from the Add call as well...

Comment: if it would be that easy... i did that before i asked. I still get the same error ( no value given to at least one parameter(smt. like that))

Comment: @Simon: Then please update your question with the modified code and the *exact* error message.

Answer (score 0):

If that's cut straight from your code then it might be giving an error because it needs a space in your queryString before the WHERE clause.